# Show and hide subrows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `jQuery` for solving the following problem. Currently I don't have any useful code for posting here.

- Initially only the Master Rows (class `term1_master` and `term2_master`) should be visible.
- By pressing the "Show" link the correlating group of rows should toogle the visibility (e. g. pressing `Show` button in `tr-class` `term1_master` should show all `tr-elements` owning class `term1`).
- The number of blocks is not fix, there can also appear `term3_master`, `term4_master` ... with their sub items.

This is my sample **HTML** code:

```
<table>
  <tr class="term1_master">
    <td>Master Row 1</td>
    <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="term2_master">
    <td>Master Row 2</td>
    <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Can you show some jQuery code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use separate classes, at all, all master rows can have one .master class. Then you can use great nextUntil() method to get what you want:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).text()=='Show') {
        $(this).closest('.master').nextUntil('.master').show();
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('.master').nextUntil('.master').hide();
        $(this).text('Show');
    }
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).text()=='Show') {
        $(this).closest('.master').nextUntil('.master').show();
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('.master').nextUntil('.master').hide();
        $(this).text('Show');
    }
});
```

```css
tr {
  display:none;
}
tr.master {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="master">
    <td>Master Row 1</td>
    <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>

<tr class="master">
    <td>Master Row 2</td>
    <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>

<tr class="master">
    <td>Master Row 3</td>
    <td><a href="">Show</a></td>
</tr><tr class="term3">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term3">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term3">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following logic inside relevant click handler to show only specific targeted follow row, depending relevant class:

```
$(function() { // ready handler
  $('table a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var trClass = $tr.attr('class').split('_').shift();
    $tr.nextAll('.' + trClass).show();
  })
});
```

[-jsFiddle-](https://jsfiddle.net/p3knw3z9/)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for the current HTML and appending term3_master, term4_master ... with their sub items.

```js
$(function() {
$('tr').not('[class$="_master"]').hide();
  $('table a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).text() === "Show") {
    $(this).text("Hide");
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var trClass = $tr.attr('class').split('_').shift();
    $tr.nextAll('.' + trClass).show();
    } else {
    $(this).text("Show")
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var trClass = $tr.attr('class').split('_').shift();
    $tr.nextAll('.' + trClass).hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="term1_master">
    <td>Master Row 1</td>
    <td><a href="#">Show</a></td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term1">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>

<tr class="term2_master">
    <td>Master Row 2</td>
    <td><a href="#">Show</a></td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 1</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 2</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr><tr class="term2">
    <td>Sub Row 3</td>
    <td>Example</td>
</tr>
</table>
```